# Do Multipart requests require special handling in spring security?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I can no longer upload a file since switching from acegi to springsecurity plugin.

there is a requestmap that is  '/coreAdminUpload/**','ROLE_CORE'

When I submit the upload form, springsecurity says I need to be authenticated? yet I am.

If I remove the encType='multipart/form-data'  from the form, I can at least get to the correct action.  If I have multipart/form-data set,  I get the following from springsecurity debug

```
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Request '/coreadminupload/saveusers' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@69160037: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@69160037: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@a53ea21: Username: admin@adminDemo; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CORE; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 41FDC51C1D2E746ED1DD77AFE864D39F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CORE'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers; Attributes: [ROLE_CORE]
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@69160037: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@a53ea21: Username: admin@adminDemo; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CORE; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 41FDC51C1D2E746ED1DD77AFE864D39F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CORE
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_CORE] one can reach [ROLE_CORE] in zero or more steps.
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Authorization successful
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2014-09-08 12:39:08,401 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /coreAdminUpload/saveUsers reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2014-09-08 12:39:08,406 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
2014-09-08 12:39:08,406 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-09-08 12:39:08,408 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Request '/login/auth' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,408 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,408 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@69160037: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@69160037: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@a53ea21: Username: admin@adminDemo; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CORE; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 41FDC51C1D2E746ED1DD77AFE864D39F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CORE'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,409 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,409 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,409 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,409 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,409 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,409 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2014-09-08 12:39:08,409 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
```

Comment: Hi mbw, what about the argument used by getFile() ? Exception said you didn't use a String.

Comment: A string is passed matching the name of the input for file selection.